# Ubuntu/WSL disappeared from Windows Terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, json

I am using WSL/Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows Terminal, and I wanted to change my font color.  When I copied settings into my `settings.json` file, the Ubuntu profile disappeared from Windows Terminal`.

My `settings.json` file looks like this:

```
{
        "$help": "https://aka.ms/terminal-documentation",
        "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
        "actions": [],
        "alwaysShowNotificationIcon": false,
        "defaultProfile": "{07b52e3e-de2c-5db4-bd2d-ba144ed6c273}",
        "firstWindowPreference": "defaultProfile",
        "profiles": 
        {
            "defaults": 
            {
                "colorScheme": "xcad_tdl",
                "font": 
                {
                    "face": "Consolas",
                    "size": 11
                },
                "historySize": 12000,
                "opacity": 95,
                "scrollbarState": "visible",
                "useAcrylic": false
            },
            "list": 
            [
                {
                    "guid": "{07b52e3e-de2c-5db4-bd2d-ba144ed6c273}",
                    "hidden": false,
                    "icon": "%userprofile%\\WindowsTerminalIcons\\ubuntu.png",
                    "name": "Ubuntu Linux",
                    "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
                    "startingDirectory": "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\home\\xcad"
                },
                {
                    "backgroundImage": "desktopWallpaper",
                    "font": 
                    {
                        "face": "Consolas"
                    },
                    "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
                    "icon": "%userprofile%\\WindowsTerminalIcons\\cmd.png",
                    "name": "Commandline"
                },
                {
                    "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
                    "hidden": true,
                    "icon": "%userprofile%\\WindowsTerminalIcons\\azure.png",
                    "name": "Azure Cloud Shell",
                    "source": "Windows.Terminal.Azure"
                }
            ]
        },
         "schemes": 

    
        [
        {
            "name": "Campbell",
            "foreground": "#A7B191", 
            "background": "#0C0C0C",
            "colors": [
                "#0C0C0C",
                "#C50F1F",
                "#13A10E",
                "#C19C00",
                "#0037DA",
                "#881798",
                "#3A96DD",
                "#CCCCCC",
                "#767676",
                "#E74856",
                "#16C60C",
                "#F9F1A5",
                "#3B78FF",
                "#B4009E",
                "#61D6D6",
                "#F2F2F2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "background": "#012456",
            "black": "#0C0C0C",
            "blue": "#0037DA",
            "brightBlack": "#767676",
            "brightBlue": "#3B78FF",
            "brightCyan": "#61D6D6",
            "brightGreen": "#16C60C",
            "brightPurple": "#B4009E",
            "brightRed": "#E74856",
            "brightWhite": "#F2F2F2",
            "brightYellow": "#F9F1A5",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#3A96DD",
            "foreground": "#CCCCCC",
            "green": "#13A10E",
            "name": "Campbell Powershell",
            "purple": "#881798",
            "red": "#C50F1F",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#CCCCCC",
            "yellow": "#C19C00"
        },
        {
            "background": "#282C34",
            "black": "#282C34",
            "blue": "#61AFEF",
            "brightBlack": "#5A6374",
            "brightBlue": "#61AFEF",
            "brightCyan": "#56B6C2",
            "brightGreen": "#98C379",
            "brightPurple": "#C678DD",
            "brightRed": "#E06C75",
            "brightWhite": "#DCDFE4",
            "brightYellow": "#E5C07B",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#56B6C2",
            "foreground": "#DCDFE4",
            "green": "#98C379",
            "name": "One Half Dark",
            "purple": "#C678DD",
            "red": "#E06C75",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#DCDFE4",
            "yellow": "#E5C07B"
        },
        {
            "background": "#FAFAFA",
            "black": "#383A42",
            "blue": "#0184BC",
            "brightBlack": "#4F525D",
            "brightBlue": "#61AFEF",
            "brightCyan": "#56B5C1",
            "brightGreen": "#98C379",
            "brightPurple": "#C577DD",
            "brightRed": "#DF6C75",
            "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
            "brightYellow": "#E4C07A",
            "cursorColor": "#4F525D",
            "cyan": "#0997B3",
            "foreground": "#383A42",
            "green": "#50A14F",
            "name": "One Half Light",
            "purple": "#A626A4",
            "red": "#E45649",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#FAFAFA",
            "yellow": "#C18301"
        },
        {
            "background": "#002B36",
            "black": "#002B36",
            "blue": "#268BD2",
            "brightBlack": "#073642",
            "brightBlue": "#839496",
            "brightCyan": "#93A1A1",
            "brightGreen": "#586E75",
            "brightPurple": "#6C71C4",
            "brightRed": "#CB4B16",
            "brightWhite": "#FDF6E3",
            "brightYellow": "#657B83",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#2AA198",
            "foreground": "#839496",
            "green": "#859900",
            "name": "Solarized Dark",
            "purple": "#D33682",
            "red": "#DC322F",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#EEE8D5",
            "yellow": "#B58900"
        },
        {
            "background": "#FDF6E3",
            "black": "#002B36",
            "blue": "#268BD2",
            "brightBlack": "#073642",
            "brightBlue": "#839496",
            "brightCyan": "#93A1A1",
            "brightGreen": "#586E75",
            "brightPurple": "#6C71C4",
            "brightRed": "#CB4B16",
            "brightWhite": "#FDF6E3",
            "brightYellow": "#657B83",
            "cursorColor": "#002B36",
            "cyan": "#2AA198",
            "foreground": "#657B83",
            "green": "#859900",
            "name": "Solarized Light",
            "purple": "#D33682",
            "red": "#DC322F",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#EEE8D5",
            "yellow": "#B58900"
        },
        {
            "background": "#000000",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#3465A4",
            "brightBlack": "#555753",
            "brightBlue": "#729FCF",
            "brightCyan": "#34E2E2",
            "brightGreen": "#8AE234",
            "brightPurple": "#AD7FA8",
            "brightRed": "#EF2929",
            "brightWhite": "#EEEEEC",
            "brightYellow": "#FCE94F",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#06989A",
            "foreground": "#D3D7CF",
            "green": "#4E9A06",
            "name": "Tango Dark",
            "purple": "#75507B",
            "red": "#CC0000",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#D3D7CF",
            "yellow": "#C4A000"
        },
        {
            "background": "#FFFFFF",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#3465A4",
            "brightBlack": "#555753",
            "brightBlue": "#729FCF",
            "brightCyan": "#34E2E2",
            "brightGreen": "#8AE234",
            "brightPurple": "#AD7FA8",
            "brightRed": "#EF2929",
            "brightWhite": "#EEEEEC",
            "brightYellow": "#FCE94F",
            "cursorColor": "#000000",
            "cyan": "#06989A",
            "foreground": "#555753",
            "green": "#4E9A06",
            "name": "Tango Light",
            "purple": "#75507B",
            "red": "#CC0000",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#D3D7CF",
            "yellow": "#C4A000"
        },
        {
            "background": "#000000",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#000080",
            "brightBlack": "#808080",
            "brightBlue": "#0000FF",
            "brightCyan": "#00FFFF",
            "brightGreen": "#00FF00",
            "brightPurple": "#FF00FF",
            "brightRed": "#FF0000",
            "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
            "brightYellow": "#FFFF00",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#008080",
            "foreground": "#C0C0C0",
            "green": "#008000",
            "name": "Vintage",
            "purple": "#800080",
            "red": "#800000",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#C0C0C0",
            "yellow": "#808000"
        },
        {
            "background": "#111927",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#004CFF",
            "brightBlack": "#666666",
            "brightBlue": "#5CB2FF",
            "brightCyan": "#5CECC6",
            "brightGreen": "#C5F467",
            "brightPurple": "#AE81FF",
            "brightRed": "#FF8484",
            "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
            "brightYellow": "#FFCC5C",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#2EE7B6",
            "foreground": "#D4D4D4",
            "green": "#9FEF00",
            "name": "xcad_hackthebox",
            "purple": "#BC3FBC",
            "red": "#FF3E3E",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#FFFFFF",
            "yellow": "#FFAF00"
        },
        {
            "background": "#1A1A1A",
            "black": "#121212",
            "blue": "#2B4FFF",
            "brightBlack": "#2F2F2F",
            "brightBlue": "#5C78FF",
            "brightCyan": "#5AC8FF",
            "brightGreen": "#905AFF",
            "brightPurple": "#5EA2FF",
            "brightRed": "#BA5AFF",
            "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
            "brightYellow": "#685AFF",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#28B9FF",
            "foreground": "#F1F1F1",
            "green": "#7129FF",
            "name": "xcad_tdl",
            "purple": "#2883FF",
            "red": "#A52AFF",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#F1F1F1",
            "yellow": "#3D2AFF"
        },
        {
            "background": "#0F0F0F",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#2878FF",
            "brightBlack": "#2F2F2F",
            "brightBlue": "#5E99FF",
            "brightCyan": "#5AD6FF",
            "brightGreen": "#FFB15A",
            "brightPurple": "#935CFF",
            "brightRed": "#FF755A",
            "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
            "brightYellow": "#FFD25A",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#28C8FF",
            "foreground": "#F1F1F1",
            "green": "#FF9A28",
            "name": "xcad_tdl_colorful",
            "purple": "#732BFF",
            "red": "#FF4C27",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#F1F1F1",
            "yellow": "#FFC72A"
        },
        {
            "background": "#0F0F0F",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#184AE8",
            "brightBlack": "#5F5F5F",
            "brightBlue": "#4771F5",
            "brightCyan": "#31C1FF",
            "brightGreen": "#FFD631",
            "brightPurple": "#7631FF",
            "brightRed": "#FF3190",
            "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
            "brightYellow": "#FF9731",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#008DCB",
            "foreground": "#D9D9D9",
            "green": "#CBA300",
            "name": "xcad_tdl_old",
            "purple": "#4300CB",
            "red": "#CB005F",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#CFCFCF",
            "yellow": "#CB6600"
        },
        {
            "background": "#282C34",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#007ACC",
            "brightBlack": "#75715E",
            "brightBlue": "#11A8CD",
            "brightCyan": "#11A8CD",
            "brightGreen": "#0DBC79",
            "brightPurple": "#AE81FF",
            "brightRed": "#DD6B65",
            "brightWhite": "#F8F8F2",
            "brightYellow": "#E6DB74",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#11A8CD",
            "foreground": "#D4D4D4",
            "green": "#0DBC79",
            "name": "xcad_vscode",
            "purple": "#BC3FBC",
            "red": "#F4423A",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#F8F8F2",
            "yellow": "#E5E510"
        }
    ],
    "showTabsInTitlebar": true,
    "tabSwitcherMode": "inOrder",
    "theme": "system",
    "useAcrylicInTabRow": true
}
```

When I click on settings it gave me warning :

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/janlu/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe/LocalState/settings.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "768",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Draft 2020-12 schemas are not yet fully supported.",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 2
}]
```

And also, when I launch Windows Terminal, it says ...

```
Settings could not be loaded from file. Check for syntax errors, including trailing commas.
* Line 2, Column 5
  Missing '}' or object member name

Temporarily using the Windows Terminal default settings.
```

Do you know how can I make my WSL work again but with a new font color?

I wanted to make it look more like [these settings](https://github.com/xcad2k/dotfiles/blob/main/Windows/WindowsTerminal/settings.json) but with a background image of my PC.

Edit:  Added screenshot based on comments:

[Possible Byte mark??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mMHG.png)

Comment: Have you got a byte order marker at the beginning of your jason file? (it doesn't like the first 2 characters)

Comment: @DavidPostill Hi I added a screen shot there but there is nothing that seems there is byte mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `settings.json` in your question seems to validate okay, so I might suspect what @DavidPostill pointed out in the comments.  I would try:

- Delete your existing `settings.json` and let Terminal regenerate it.
- Ubuntu *should* come back when it scans for the list of profiles to create.  At least I'm hoping that you won't get the error message any longer.
- Either -- Copy your settings from your question here and paste them back over the newly generated config.  If you start getting the error again, then there's something in the config that we're just not seeing.  Proceed to the next step (or just start with the next step).
- It's rare that you should need to manually edit the `settings.json` nowadays.  The website you followed is probably a bit out of date, since Windows Terminal now has a graphical interface for modifying most settings (theme/colors included).  If Terminal regenerates the `settings.json` ok, then you might just try adding a color scheme directly in the *Settings* menu.  If you need the exact numeric codes, you can then modify *just* that scheme in the `settings.json` manually.

*Hopefully* this will help you recover your settings (and Ubuntu/WSL profile).

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem :)